# jquery accordion formatting differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.compactcourse.com/js/accordionNew.js" language="javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h1>Toggle Panels</h1>
<div id="notaccordion">
<h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
<div>

Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.

</div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
<div>

Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
suscipit faucibus urna.

</div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
<div>

Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
<ul>
    <li>List item one</li>
    <li>List item two</li>
    <li>List item three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
<div>

Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
mauris vel est.

Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
inceptos himenaeos.

</div>
</div>
```

The above is the code I've put into a raw html code box on one page of my wordpress site. Here's the link: [compactcourse.com/sloths](http://www.compactcourse.com/sloths/)

As you can see, the jquery accordions don't look like the normal format that they should look like. If you paste the code above into a raw html editor, the preview will show up how it should normally. any ideas about why this is screwing up?

Comment: Did you add the base jQuery UI `css`?

Comment: @Dom look at the second line of his code.  Yes, he did

Comment: @Ennui sorry I meant jqueryUI script. You have errors on your page. Make sure to include jQuery script ***FIRST*** then jQueryUI script.

Comment: Yeah I'm not entirely sure what's going on here.  I'm assuming the second script call to `accordionNew.js` (which I didn't even notice initially) is just the accordion part of jQuery UI...

Comment: hey, sorry, but the second one, accordionNew.js, is custom jquery code. it just lets me open more than one accordion at a time

Comment: @user2469006 I updated my answer with a fix for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your website's CSS is probably interfering with the `jquery-ui` CSS.  That is to say that some of the CSS rules used by your site's theme are more specific and therefore overwrite some of the CSS rules that are being imported from the `link` tag at the top of your HTML code.

That would also explain why this code looks fine in a raw HTML editor (which is not loading additional resources / stylesheets) but not on your site.  You need to track down the CSS from your theme that is interfering and alter either the markup or CSS accordingly.

Here are a few guides / primers to the concept of CSS specificity:

- [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)
- [Smashing Mag](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)
- [Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-understanding-css-specificity/)

**edit:** the only obvious problem I see is the margin on the bottom of the accordion's `h3` headings as Daniel pointed out in his answer.  The code from your theme CSS causing this problem is this:

```
div.entry-content h3, div.entry-content h4, 
div.entry-content h5, div.entry-content h6 { 
    margin: 0 0 15px; 
}
```

To fix this you need to overwrite the margin for `h3` tags within the accordion.  Adding this CSS rule to your page should do it:

```
#notaccordion h3 { 
    margin-bottom: 0; 
}
```

You can either put that in between `<style></style>` tags or simply add it to one of the external stylesheets loaded by your theme on that page.  The former is a rather sloppy method but as your page's code is already pretty much a horrible cobbled-together codepasta nightmare from a standards perspective it wouldn't really be making things that much worse.

Comment: hahaha. thanks for the help. just wondering, in what way is my code so bad? will it cause inefficiencies that'll affect load times? or is it just unorganized?

Comment: @user2469006 Mostly it's just disorganized and not standards compliant (multiple nested `head` and `body` tags, multiple `doctype` declarations, duplicate element `id`s and so forth) but I certainly imagine it could be further optimized for load times.  This link to a HTML validator helps show what I mean: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.compactcourse.com%2Fsloths%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: @user2469006 Also please remember to upvote and mark as the confirmed answer (the little check box below the vote buttons) if this solution worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The css in your theme is overriding jquery ui styles. The headings all have a 15px margin added to the bottom.

Add this to your themes CSS.
div.entry-content .ui-accordion h3{margin-bottom:0;}